# Modifiquei sem querer a branch do Git de meu projeto no android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, git, github

Gente, eu estava trabalhando no meu projeto, quando cliquei em algo sem querer, e aparentemente "perdi" as versões mais novas.
Me apareceu esta mensagem em meu console do android studio:

```
Warning: you are leaving 19 commits behind, not connected to
any of your branches:
  d78081a App cliente Versão 1.5.7
  9d19da0 App cliente Versão 1.5.6
  861890d App cliente Versão 1.5.5
  15ff813 App cliente Versão 1.5.4
 ... and 15 more.
If you want to keep them by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:
 git branch <new-branch-name> d78081a
Switched to branch 'master'
```

E, não sei o que deve ser feito

Comment: Em qual branch vc está? é só dar checkout pra branch que vc deseja.

Comment: fui parar em um bem antigo, não conhecia o checkout mas vou ler sobre, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, aparentemente quando as versões somem fica um histórico:
Cole isso no terminal

```
git reflog
```

então você precisa criar um novo branch e fazer referência ao que sumiu

```
git branch new-branch ba5a739
```

onde o new-branch é o nome do branch e o número ao lado é o número de referência

e então você volta o código ao branch antigo com o seguinte código:

```
git reset --hard ba5a739
```

e então todo o código vai voltar ao normal